# Passing value from one html to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have basic web application developed in node.js,mongodb and jquery/javascript. I have login page (login.html [public folder]) with username and password inputs. On login action REST API gets data from mongodb and sends as JSON object back to login.html. On success i will redirect to dashboard.html with `window.location("/")`. Now i have a `<a>` in dashboard where i want to set the name from the JSON object.

I saw one solution with `localstorage`, is there any other way to do this without using any framework like knockout,backbone or angualr. I am looking for modeling the JSON object at sucess call back from REST API and share the model at other pages.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a backend or localstorage, your only other option is cookies.

Comment: I tried that option , but if the user choose to disable the cookies ? Currently i am sending with the url like :                `var url = "Dashboard.htm?name=" + fullname'               window.location.href = url; . But this expose my data. If there are some other way that will be great !

Comment: If they disable cookies and you can't use localstorage or backend storage get params (like you're using) are your only option, you can use some js to serialize and deserialize if you don't want the data easily read. This is not a secure approach but it is an option.